# How do you access a result field by columnname in oracledb / nodejs?

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am using oracledb (5.5.0).

When I do a SELECT statement in OracleDB, I am able to access the result by the index of the column.  Is there a way to access it by the column name?

My code looks like this:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
...

    //do a simple select statement
    select = async(query, params) => {
        console.log("Selecting (5468468466)... ");             
           
        let conn;
        try{
            conn = await this.getDatabaseConnectionOracle();

            const result  = await conn.execute(query, params);

            console.log("result: ");
            console.log(result);

            let rows = result.rows;
            rows.forEach( (row) => {
                console.log(`Lowercase: ${row.fullname} `);
                console.log(`Uppercase: ${row.FULLNAME} `);  
                console.log(`row[0]: ${row[0]} `);  

              });
            return result.rows;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error in oracle.select(): ' , error);
        } finally {
            if (conn) {
                await conn.close();
              }

        }

    }
```

My output looks like this:

```
Selecting (5468468466)...

result: 
{
  metaData: [
    { name: 'USERID' },
    { name: 'FULLNAME' }
  ],
  rows: [
    [
      '123456789',
    'My Full Name'
    ]
  ]
}

Lowercase: undefined
Uppercase: undefined
row[0]: 123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
const options = { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT };
const result  = await conn.execute(query, params,options);

let rows = result.rows;

rows.forEach( (row) => {
    console.log(row);

    //Any of these will work
    console.log(`Uppercase: ${row.FULLNAME} `);     

    console.log(`row['FULLNAME']: ${row['FULLNAME']} `);         

    console.log(`row[0]: ${row[0]} `);  

});
```